# length of each word in list (python) and then removing that word if that word is less than some number(suppose 5)

Tags: python

how can i find the length of each word in list(python) and then remove that particular word if the length of that word is less than some number(suppose 5):
 i'm beginner in python so please need your help guys
e.g:

```
visited_cities = ["New York", "Shanghai", "Munich", "Toyko", "Dubai", "Mexico City", "São Paulo", "Hyderabad"]
```

in the above list i need to find the length of each word in list and if that length is less than 5 i should remove that how to to it ?
suppose i'm taking the word Dubai and its length is 5 ..now i have to remove that single word from the list and print the new list

Answer (score 1):

Just use a list comprehension

```
>>> visited_cities = ["New York", "Shanghai", "Munich", "Toyko", "Dubai", "Mexico City", "São Paulo", "Hyderabad"] 
>>> [city for city in visited_cities if len(city)>5]
['New York', 'Shanghai', 'Munich', 'Mexico City', 'S\xc3\xa3o Paulo', 'Hyderabad']
```

Answer (score 0):

An expanded version of Sunitha's answer:

```
visited_cities = ["New York", "Shanghai", "Munich", "Toyko", "Dubai", "Mexico City", "São Paulo", "Hyderabad"]
new_cities=[] #start with no cities found
for city in visited_cities: #loop through cities
    if len(city)>5: #if the length is more than 5
        new_cities.append(city) #add it to the new list of cities
print(new_cities)
```